# Error 'Extensions' version 1.1.20200923 cannot be downloaded. Is it a built-in module? al efectuar build a cualquier objeto

Tags: genexus15

Acabo de instalar Genexus 15 U12 con java y al efectuar Build me da el siguiente error:

```
========== Build All started ==========
========== Copying Module 'GeneXus' started ==========
Copying Module 'GeneXus' Success
========== Copying Module 'Extensions' started ==========
**error: 'Extensions' version 1.1.20200923 cannot be downloaded. Is it a built-in module? Try execute "genexus.exe /install" command. Otherwise, you need to update the module version to an accessible one.**
Copying Module 'Extensions' Success
========== Target Environment update started ==========
```

¿Alguien puede saber a qué se debe este error y cómo resolverlo?